# Wordpress get_post_gallery_images function not working

Tags: wordpress, amp-html

I am using `get_post_gallery_images` Wordpress function in AMP (accelerated mobile pages) condition. This function is not working. Please any one have any idea about this. Why this wordpress function is not giving output.

Comment: Are you loading wordpress files correctly? or are you using a plugin?

Comment: Can you add some code to give more context? What have you tried and is not working

Comment: Using plugin for AMP but function use condition based.

Comment: `$gallery = get_post_gallery_images( get_the_ID() );
    print_r( $gallery );
   if ( ! empty( $gallery ) && is_array( $gallery ) && isset( $gallery['ids'] ) ) {

   $thumbnail_ids = explode( ',', $gallery['ids'] );
   $gal_count     = 1;

   foreach ( $thumbnail_ids as $thumbnail_id ) {

   $thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );`